# Maximums of multiple data.table subsets

Tags: r, data.table, subset

Given is a *data.table* with base data, startIndex of the subsets, duration of subsets. For each subset each duration is applied.

```
base <- data.table(idx=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), val=c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20))
startIndex <- c(2, 4, 7, 9)
duration <- c(1,2,3)
```

Is there some elegant way to get the maximum *val* per subset defined by startIndex and duration, with the result shown below? For example, the first subset is defined by startIndex=2 and duration=1, which means that the max between index 2 and 3 is 13.

```
Result:
   idxStart idxEnd max
1:        2      3  13
2:        4      5  15
3:        7      8  18
4:        2      4  14
5:        4      6  16
6:        7      9  19
7:        2      5  15
8:        4      7  17
9:        7     10  20
```

thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` approach using a non-equi join. First, use `expand.grid` for combinations of start index and duration. Then, calculate the end index for each row. Then join with your `base`, where the index `idx` falls between the start and end, and keep the maximum `val`.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(expand.grid(idxStart = startIndex, Duration = duration)) 

dt[ , idxEnd := idxStart + Duration][
  base, Max := max(val), on = .(idxStart <= idx, idxEnd >= idx), by = .EACHI]
```

**Output**

```
    idxStart Duration idxEnd Max
 1:        2        1      3  13
 2:        4        1      5  15
 3:        7        1      8  18
 4:        9        1     10  20
 5:        2        2      4  14
 6:        4        2      6  16
 7:        7        2      9  19
 8:        9        2     11  20
 9:        2        3      5  15
10:        4        3      7  17
11:        7        3     10  20
12:        9        3     12  20
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a particularly elegant solution here, but I think a map function should get the job done. This is brute forcing each combination through so there may be a more efficient solution, but it should work.

```
library(data.table)
base <- data.table(idx=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), val=c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20))
startIndex <- c(2, 4, 7, 9)
duration <- c(1,2,3)
combos <- expand.grid(startIndex = startIndex, 
                      duration = duration) %>% 
  mutate(endIndex = startIndex + duration)
max_slices <- map2(combos$startIndex, combos$endIndex, function(startIndex, endIndex){
  slice(base, startIndex, endIndex) %>% 
    select(val) %>% 
    max()
}) %>% 
  as.numeric()
result <- combos %>% 
  cbind(max = max_slices)
```

Result:

```
   startIndex duration endIndex max
1           2        1        3  13
2           4        1        5  15
3           7        1        8  18
4           9        1       10  20
5           2        2        4  14
6           4        2        6  16
7           7        2        9  19
8           9        2       11  19
9           2        3        5  15
10          4        3        7  17
11          7        3       10  20
12          9        3       12  19
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using the map function however I don't think I have kept the function as a data.table so this may not be satisfactory. Please let me know if not and I can take another look or refer to another answer. One option would be to run the data.table function on the output.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)

base <- data.table(idx=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), val=c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20))
startIndex <- c(2, 4, 7, 9)
duration <- c(1,2,3)

crossing(startIndex, duration) %>% 
  data.table() %>% 
  mutate(max = map2_dbl(startIndex, duration, ~max(base$val[.x:(.x + .y)])))
#> Source: local data table [12 x 3]
#> Call:   copy(`_DT1`)[, `:=`(max = map2_dbl(startIndex, duration, ~max(..base$val[.x:(.x + 
#>     .y)])))]
#> 
#>   startIndex duration   max
#>        <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1          2        1    13
#> 2          2        2    14
#> 3          2        3    15
#> 4          4        1    15
#> 5          4        2    16
#> 6          4        3    17
#> # ... with 6 more rows
#> 
#> # Use as.data.table()/as.data.frame()/as_tibble() to access results
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>